# Return an array of NSNumbers with NSIntegers as parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Return an array of NSNumbers with NSIntegers as parameters

I am trying to create an array of `NSNumbers` between two integers, inclusively. 
Two parameters are provided `number` and `otherNumber`

Note: either `number` or `otherNumber` may be the lower number, but the string always includes numbers from lowest to highest.

I want to be able to return an array of `NSNumber` between two integers, inclusively.

I am not getting any compiling errors the program runs, however, it's not passing the unit tests. Am I missing something? Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
- (NSArray *) arrayOfNumbersBetweenNumber:(NSInteger)number andOtherNumber: (NSInteger)otherNumber {

NSNumber *newNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:number];
NSNumber *otherNewNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:otherNumber];

NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:newNumber, otherNewNumber, nil];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES];
[mutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSArray *myArray = [mutableArray copy];
return myArray;
```

Comment: You are only adding two numbers, your two bounds, to the array, not all of the intermediary numbers.  Also adding numbers and then sorting is pretty inefficient.  You can use a simple `for` loop

Comment: Also, the `[mutableArray copy]` at the end is fairly pointless - Either just return `mutableArray` or make an immutable copy via `[NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective-C

```
- (NSArray *)arrayOfNumbersBetweenNumber:(NSInteger)number andOtherNumber:(NSInteger)otherNumber {
    NSMutableArray *mutableRange = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSInteger i = number; i <= otherNumber; i++)  {
        [mutableRange addObject:@(i)];
    }
    return [mutableRange copy];
}
```

Comment: You need to handle the case where `otherNumber` < `number`

Comment: @Paulw11 This is example code, not production code. But 10---7 does not crash, it returns `()` because the for loop comparison fails immediately. There are other input conditions that could also be checked such as a range that is so large as to cause a memory crash, think: 1...a_very_big_number. FWIW, I did not down vote your answer.

Comment: fair enough, I agree there is no need to spoon-feed, but the condition for either number to be the larger was stated in the problem.  The other conditions are implicit rather than explicit. Hey I decided to leave the OP some work to convert it to Objective C and got a down vote for my trouble :)

Comment: Yeah, I too leaned my lesson about answering the another language. I provided an answer since the OP did show some work. It is very difficule today starting out, the apps require a lot of knowledge, that is they are not simple, and there is so much to learn.

Comment: Ironically, I would normally prefer objective-C and never use Swift, but you know, Playgrounds...

Comment: Actually I hate the playgrounds, They seem to run the code on their own schedule, maybe in a few revs. I just have a few basic apps ready to plug my code into

Comment: That is what I normally do too, but this code was simple enough and I just wanted to make sure the syntax was right

Answer (score -1):

You are only adding two numbers, your two bounds, to the array, not all of the intermediary numbers. Also adding numbers and then sorting is pretty inefficient. You can use a simple for loop.

Here is an answer in Swift because a Playground made it easier and I have to leave you some work :)

```
func arrayOfNumbersBetween(startNumber:NSInteger, endNumber:NSInteger) -> NSArray {
    let loopStart=min(startNumber,endNumber)
    let loopEnd=max(startNumber, endNumber)

    let returnArray=NSMutableArray()

    for number in loopStart...loopEnd {
        returnArray.addObject(NSNumber(integer: number))
    }

    return returnArray 
}
```